# Wordpress post images not showing up in Google plus post

Tags: wordpress, google-plus

Wordpress post images aren't showing up in Google plus posts.

I have a Wordpress blog. When I post my article (which has more images) the link in Google Plus is not showing any of my post image beside my post title and description.

My images are there in www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/sampleimage.jpg. when I paste this URL in browser it shows the image, but when I post the URL in Google plus post it doesn't show images.

Has anyone faced the same issue? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the og:image meta tag? There's a lot of discussion about it on this forum (http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/VPelac6eozA), but I find that the og:image works perfectl for me.

Just add this to your head:

```
<meta property='og:image' content='http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/sampleimage.jpg'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, but with Facebook. og:image works for Facebook, but Google+ requires different markup:

```
<meta itemprop="image" content="yourimageurl.png">
```

I wrote a tutorial for getting images working properly on Google+, Facebook, and Twitter since they all have different markup. Hopefully it'll help you out.

[How to Get Facebook, Twitter, & Google+ to Pull the Correct Image](https://turbofuture.com/internet/Fixed-Incorrect-Blog-Post-Image-on-Google-Facebook-and-Twitter)